# Complexity of the algorithms for Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, svd

As said in the title, I would like to find out something on the numerical algorithms for computing the SVD decomposition of a rectangular matrix, with particular regard to their the computational complexity. Can anybody suggest some references on the topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a link to a thorough and authoritative source:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf

Inderjit Dhillon is a leading expert on eigenvalues.

Comment: This reference is very complete but does it have explicit worstcase complexity bounds? It would be really nice to know the complexity of each algorithm in terms of eg matrix size, bit-size for entries, desired accuracy and condition numbers. Those become very handy when you need to write a report or quickly check a bound.